# VBA to copy from one workbook and paste to another

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

**JOB:** To copy RANGE from one WORKBOOK to ANOTHER (ANOTHER workbook exists and needs to be opened)

1. Copy range:

   ```
   `Worksheets("paste").Range("A2:BD500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy`
   ```
2. Open new file:

   `Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Test\test.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="WriteFile"`
3. Activate sheet and paste @RANGE A6

   `Windows("test.xlsx").Activate
       Selection.Range("A6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
           :=False, Transpose:=False`

**PROBLEM: It doesn't paste in A6!!!! It goes in whatever cell!!!!**

Comment: post your code as it is in your workbook.   Very hard to Discern what the issue is from bullet points.......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your current selection in the test.xlsx workbook opens to D5 then using `Selection.Range("A6")` references D10, not A6.

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Test\test.xlsx", WriteResPassword:="WriteFile")

With Worksheets("paste")
    .Range("A2:BD500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, "A").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). You should never rely on a static cell or cells being the current selection when opening a workbook.

Comment: This helped a lot!!! It works on a test sheet but actual sheet is more complex and I'm getting "pastespecial method of range class failed 1004" any idea how to by pass that?

Comment: Error is dispalyed @  wb.Worksheets(1).Cells(6, "A").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to copy a specific range between workbooks:

```
Workbooks(source).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:BD500").Copy _
    Workbooks(destination).Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A6")
```